# windows driver load dependencies in INF file

Tags: windows, wdf, umdf

My UMDF driver (myUMDF.dll) has dependency on one KMDF driver (someKMDF.sys) which is installed through separate INF file.

In my INF file, I want to set dependencies that myUMDF.dll will ONLY be installed once someKMDF.sys  driver is already installed.

In myUMDF driver INF file, I have mentioned this dependency as

---

[myUMDF_Driver_Install]

UmdfLibraryVersion=1.11.0

ServiceBinary=%12%\UMDF\myUMDF.dll

Dependencies=someKMDF.sys

---

But this does not reflect in desired driver load order.

Could anyone suggest, How to mention dependency on some external sys file in driver's INF file?

Thank you.